# What is the probability that you identify correctly each painter and her painting?

Tags: probability

> At an art gallery, you enter a room where $6$ paintings are hung on its walls.  Four people are in the room. If you know that one of these people is not a painter and the other three are the painters of three of the works exhibited, what is the probability that you identify correctly each painter and her painting?

My analysis:

First there is only one correct way of identifying each painter with her painting.  I know that only $3$ are painters and one is not, so I should identify $3$ distinct persons with $6$ distinct paintings. I assume there should be a permutation of $6P3=120$ and the probability must be $1/120$, but according to the mcq the correct answer is:$1/480$.

How should I proceed?

Comment: The wording of the question could be improved.  Evidently, the author meant that you know that three of the four people present are among the six painters, but that you do not know which three of the four people are the painters.  To get the desired answer, you need to multiply by the probability that you correctly identify all three painters among the $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of selecting three of the four people in the room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done by matching the painters up with their paintings, one after the other, probability-tree style.

First, you have to pick one of the $3$ painters out of the $4$ people $\frac{3}{4}$. Then, you have to pick the 1 painting they painted out of $6$. 
Probability of doing this is $\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{1}{6}$.
Next, there are $2$ painters left out of $3$ people, and $5$ paintings left. 
Probability of getting both the first pick correct, and the second is $\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{5}$.

Therefore, the probability of getting all 3 correct is $\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{480}$

Comment: Why is the probability of picking one painter out of 4 people 3 over 4 instead of 1/4?

Comment: When first choosing a painter, it doesn't matter which painter you get, because you haven't picked a painting yet. All that matters is you don't get the person who isn't a painter.